# UpFileCopyExW reports 0 with ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND on an existing file

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, file-copying

**Context:**

I have an application that searches files in a directory using `QDirIterator`, filters and copies specific files.

**Problem:**

Using the results from [QDirIterator::next()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror), I ensure the file exists (as a unnecessary safe measure) using [QFile::exists(QString)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-#ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) which is valid.

[GetLastError()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) reports [ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-#ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) error:

> ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> 2 (0x2)
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.

**The core code: (see bottom for full details)**

```
     // QString src (src file location), dst (destination file location)

     QFileInfo fi(m_src);
     QString dir = fi.dir().path();
     const wchar_t* dirC = toLPCWSTR(dir);
     QString src = QString(m_src).replace("/", "\\");
     QString dst = QString(m_src).replace("/", "\\");
     const wchar_t* localC_src = toLPCWSTR(src);
     const wchar_t* localC_dst = toLPCWSTR(dst);

     auto rc = CopyFileExW(localC_src, localC_dst, &BackupManager::copyProgress, this, &bStopBackup, 0);
     if (rc == 0) {

          DWORD lastError = GetLastError(); // Error = 0x32
          bool dirExist = DirExists(dirC); // true
          bool fileExists = FileExists(localC_src); // true

          printWarning(TAG, QString("File Copy Error: %1").arg(getLastErrorMsg()));
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
          if (FileExists(localC_src)) {
               qDebug() << "#FailedCopy: Windows file exists but copy failed" << src;  // this gets hit using the implemented c-style cast 
          }
          else {
               if (QFile::exists(src)) {
                    // =================================================
                    // < ------------------------------------- This is gets triggered
                    // =================================================

                    qDebug() << "#FailedCopy: Windows is really being full of shit! " << src;   // this always gets triggered when using QString::toStdWString.c_str()
               }
               else {
                    qDebug() << "#FailedCopy: Windows file copy failed outright" << src; 
               }
          }
          // ...
    } else {
          // success
    }
```

**Question:**

What doesn't make sense to me is why `QFile::exists(String)` reports the file as found by `FileCopyExW` says the system cannot find the specified file. What am I missing?

---

**Image of debugger:**

[image]

**Full Code Implemenation:**

```
static QString toString(HRESULT hr)
{
     _com_error err{hr};
     const TCHAR* lastError = err.ErrorMessage();
     return QStringLiteral("Error 0x%1: %2").arg((quint32)hr, 8, 16, QLatin1Char('0'))
            .arg(lastError);
}

static QString getLastErrorMsg()
{
     DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
     QString s = toString(HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(lastError));
     return s;
}

BOOL FileExists(LPCWSTR szPath)
{
     DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(szPath);

     return (dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES &&
             !(dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
}

// not used
static const wchar_t* toLPCWSTR(QString s)
{
     std::wstring dstWString = s.toStdWString();
     const wchar_t* localC_src = dstWString.c_str();
     return localC_src;
}

static bool DirExists(LPCWSTR szPath)
{
     DWORD ftyp = GetFileAttributes(szPath);
     if (ftyp == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
          return false;  //something is wrong with your path!

     if (ftyp & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
          return true;   // this is a directory!

     return false;    // this is not a directory!
}

BackupResult BackupManager::copyFile(QString m_src, QString m_dst)
{
     QFileInfo fi(m_src);
     QString dir = fi.dir().path();
     const wchar_t* dirC = toLPCWSTR(dir);
     QString src = QString(m_src).replace("/", "\\");
     QString dst = QString(m_src).replace("/", "\\");
     const wchar_t* localC_src = toLPCWSTR(src);
     const wchar_t* localC_dst = toLPCWSTR(dst);

// c-style casts
//     LPCWSTR localC_src = (LPCWSTR) src.utf16();
//     LPCWSTR localC_dst = (LPCWSTR) dst.utf16();
//     LPCWSTR dirC = (LPCWSTR) dir.utf16();

     auto rc = CopyFileExW(localC_src, localC_dst, &BackupManager::copyProgress, this, &bStopBackup, 0);
     if (rc == 0) {

          DWORD lastError = GetLastError(); // Error = 0x2 (2)
          bool dirExist = DirExists(dirC); // false
          bool fileExists = FileExists(localC_src); // false

          printWarning(TAG, QString("File Copy Error: %1").arg(getLastErrorMsg()));
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
          if (FileExists(localC_src)) {
               qDebug() << "#FailedCopy: Windows file exists but copy failed" << src; // this gets hit using the implemented c-style cast 
          }
          else {
               if (QFile::exists(src)) {
                    qDebug() << "#FailedCopy: Windows is really being full of shit! " << src;   // this always gets triggered when using QString::toStdWString.c_str()
               }
               else {
                    qDebug() << "#FailedCopy: Windows file copy failed outright" << src;
               }
          }
#endif
          // copy failed
          return BackupResult::IOError;
     }

     // copy success
     return BackupResult::Success;
}
```

---

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comment by @john, I had an issue with the destination file pointing to the source file which obviously doesn't work well.

Having fixed this issue, this highlighted another error [ERROR_INVALID_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-#ERROR_INVALID_NAME):

> ERROR_INVALID_NAME
>
> 123 (0x7B)
>
> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I resolved this by way of the posted solution.

Comment: `localC_src` and `localC_dst` have the same value. Maybe `QString dst = QString(m_src).replace("/", "\\");` is a typo for something like `QString dst = QString(m_dst).replace("/", "\\");`?

Comment: On Windows, you don't have to programatically replace forward slashes with backslashes.  The OS will correctly translate.

Comment: One other thing - you are passing your `QString` instances by value to other functions.  Pass strings that aren't meant to be modified as const references (e.g. `const QString& s`.  Not only is that more efficient, but it will also enable you to pass raw pointers and string literals to the same implementation.

Comment: @john you are quite correct, this was off of another test by copying to the same folder while attempting to fix another issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @selbie I intended on doing this a while back - will add it now, thank you!

Comment: @sel *"you don't have to programatically replace forward slashes with backslashes. The OS will correctly translate"* - Leaving the translation to the OS comes with a hidden cost: A hard limit of 260 characters per pathname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function is bugged:

```
// not used
static const wchar_t* toLPCWSTR(QString s)
{
     std::wstring dstWString = s.toStdWString();
     const wchar_t* localC_src = dstWString.c_str();
     return localC_src;
}
```

You are returning a raw pointer of a string that has already been deconstructed.

Hence, these two lines:

```
 const wchar_t* localC_src = toLPCWSTR(src);
 const wchar_t* localC_dst = toLPCWSTR(dst);
```

Are undefined behavior, but the most likely result is that `localC_src` and `localC_dst` are pointing to free'd memory.

Better to keep the `std::wstring` you converted with around while the pointer inside is still being referenced

```
std::wstring strSrc = src.toStdWString();
std::wstring strDst = dst.toStdWString();

const wchar_t* localC_src = strSrc.c_str();
const wchar_t* localC_dst = strDst.c_str();
```

Comment: thank you for you assistance - it was a simple error on my part which I don't think will be useful to anyone. I will be closing the question, but would like to thank you for you help!

Comment: **Don't close the question.**  Accept (and\or upvote) the answer that helped you!  This bug is very common and would be useful to others that hit similar errors.